# How long is a gem5 build with "gem5 scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j9" expected to take on a virtual machine?

Tags: gem5

first time working with gem5,according to gem5.org the following build command should take about 15 minutes or so to complete,  build/X86/gem5.opt -j9. But its been more than an hour since the build started and its not complete yet, has anyone experienced the same issue? is it normal? My machine has 8 cores and I've allocated 16 gigs of memory for VMware on which am running the build. Can it be a hardware problem such as not enough memory?
So far I have started the build process from scratch a few times with the same results, I've also tried it on a different virtualization platform (Virtualbox) but Its taking the same amount of time to build.
Thanks!

Comment: On a 4-core machine, any build from scratch takes around 50 minutes for me. If you are running on a virtual environment, it will take *way* more than that.

Comment: I reproduce @DanielCarvalho on a 8 core machine (25 minutes, [documented here](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#p51)). BTW, I might be able to reduce that by 30-40% in the coming weeks: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/pull/2445 | https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-572

Comment: @DanielCarvalho I was able to make it work using an 8 core machine. Thanks a lot for your input.